# Who is the current owner of patent US 618,593 S

Tags: ownership

In reference to the patent: [USD618593](https://www.google.com/patents/USD618593)

Can you please tell me if Jose Ramon Aranda, Martin Aranda, and Pablo Aranda are still the owners of these patents?

Answer (score 1):

I looked on the [US Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) website for information. There are no assignments listed so I'm guessing either the original inventors are still the owners or else you would have to ask them. The correspondence address is listed as:

```
DINSMORE & SHOHL LLP
FIFTH THIRD CENTER, ONE SOUTH MAIN STREET 
SUITE 1300 
DAYTON OH 45402-2023
Customer Number: 23368
```

I'm assuming that is the patent attorney's address.